# osclass specific category at home page

Tags: php, osclass

I am using osclass 3.1.2 version with modern theme. I have created 2 main categories paid and free which also contains one subcategory each named as premium ads and free ads. now I want to display only premium ads on my sites home page so how can I do this?

I have found this code from http://doc.osclass.org/Display_only_certain_type_of_listings

But not able to merge with my code please help.

Comment: anybody help me i am new to osclass.....

Comment: have you tried any code yet?

Comment: hay! is any osclass expert here who can help me?

Comment: is anyone osclass expert here who understand my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for replies. finally i have found my answer.following code is perfect solution of my problem.

```
<?php osc_query_item("category=99");
if( osc_count_custom_items() == 0) { ?>
    <p class="empty"><?php _e('No Listings', 'modern') ; ?></p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
            <?php $class = "even"; ?>
            <?php while ( osc_has_custom_items() ) { ?>
             <tr class="<?php echo $class. (osc_item_is_premium()?" premium":"") ; ?>">
                    <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
                     <td class="photo">
                        <?php if( osc_count_item_resources() ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo osc_item_url() ; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_thumbnail_url() ; ?>" width="75" height="56" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />
                            </a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo osc_current_web_theme_url('images/no_photo.gif') ; ?>" alt="" title=""/>
                        <?php } ?>
                     </td>
                    <?php } ?>
                     <td class="text">
                         <h3><a href="<?php echo osc_item_url() ; ?>"><?php echo osc_item_title() ; ?></a></h3>
                         <p><strong><?php if( osc_price_enabled_at_items() ) { echo osc_item_formated_price() ; ?> - <?php } echo osc_item_city(); ?> (<?php echo osc_item_region();?>) - <?php echo osc_format_date(osc_item_pub_date()); ?></strong></p>
                         <p><?php echo osc_highlight( strip_tags( osc_item_description() ) ) ; ?></p>
                     </td>                                       
                 </tr>
                <?php $class = ($class == 'even') ? 'odd' : 'even' ; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php }; ?>
```